# MySQL: how to get records with count > 1?

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a sql like this:

```
SELECT *, count(*) as cc 
FROM manytomany 
GROUP BY aid, bid
ORDER BY cc DESC
```

which return all records with the count #.

however, what can I do if I only want to get the ones with count > 1?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
SELECT *, count(*) as cc 
FROM manytomany 
GROUP BY aid, bid
HAVING 1 < count(*)
ORDER BY cc DESC
```

Comment: I've never written it as `HAVING 1 < count(*)`, but it works.

Comment: Why would you put the 1 on the left hand side of the expression?  Sure, it's logically consistent, but just curious...

Comment: readability.  it's easier to quickly grasp the structure of the expression if the infix operator is closer to the start of the expression: `1 < bla-bla-bla-bla...` rather than `bla-bla-bla-bla > 1`

Comment: Good answer, though I have to disagree on the readability point.  For me at least `count > 1` is more readable (and just as importantly, more _intuitively_ readable) than `1 < count`.  You might have a point if the `bla-bla-bla...` is something much longer than just `count`, but in that case it seems like to get maximum readability you'd want to alias it with an `AS bla` and then use `bla > 1`.

Comment: @gahooa where there's a language difference between = and ==, it's not easy to spot typos in the number of = signs used.. Getting in the habit of putting the number on the left can help identify these errors early on... for example.. if ($aardvarks = 1) is valid but if (1 = $aardvarks) is not. Need for consistency would suggest that all tests would be then written like this and the "habit" gets passed around. Personally, I find it less readable but I still try to put the number on the left for "safety"

Answer (score 3):

You need a [HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) clause, for example:

```
SELECT *, count(*) as cc 
FROM manytomany 
GROUP BY aid, bid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY cc DESC
```

Here's some [background](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3469351/The-HAVING-and-GROUP-BY-SQL-clauses.htm).

Answer (score 2):

The `HAVING` clause

```
   SELECT *, count(*) as cc 
    FROM manytomany 
    GROUP BY aid, bid
    HAVING cc > 1
    ORDER BY cc DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the having clause.

```
SELECT *, count(*) as cc
FROM manytomany
GROUP BY aid, bid
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY cc DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, count(*) as cc 
FROM manytomany 
GROUP BY aid, bid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY cc DESC
```

I don't use MySQL, but it should support HAVING -it has been around for along time.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, count(*) as cc 
FROM manytomany 
GROUP BY aid, bid
HAVING cc>1
ORDER BY cc DESC
```